# Deleted System Dialer app

Tags: applications, rom, system, phone-app

I have a CUSTOM rom. I deleted system Dialer app. Is it possible to recover it, or fix it? I can't get calls, can't make calls, but I can write & receive messages. Other dialers don't work and it says "this device does not support this function"

Comment: Reinstall the ROM. You probably still have the ZIP file on your device.

Comment: Is it possible to fix it without reinstalling?

Comment: You can probably just copy the required files and folders from the ZIP and fix their permissions, but reflashing is still the easiest solution (you don't lose your data, by the way, only if you choose to wipe `/data/`).

Comment: You should be able to just dirty flash the ROM... Meaning flash it and do not wipe anything. May have to reflash Gapps as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer&hl=en

Does this kind of dialer also dowsn't work??

If it doesn't, the your only choice is to dirty flash your current rom from rcovery